# Eliminate Scroll Bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is the website I am trying to eliminate the scrollbar from http://tubagency.com/

I have this code for the images:

```
.pic {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    animation: anima 2s;
    -webkit-animation: anima 2s;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.pic-image {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    height:67%;
}
```

See how the scroll bar shows up, I want a static page. How could that be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Remove the scroll bar from the scroll bar from the page, by adding this to the body element. If that is what you meant in your question.

Comment: You sir, are a genious. Thank you very much.